# working url rewriting with Internal Server Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Am trying to do a url rewriting with .htaccess which is working but the problem is that when I click on the link it displays url rewriting well on the address bar but the page displays this error Internal Server Error and I have turn on the necessary thing I need to turn on in my wamp like (LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so) so how can I fix this below is my code below with these page index.php, venues.php(which contain the classes), landing.php(display the url rewiting well on the address bar but display Internal Server Error) and .htaccess.

```
index.php
include_once("venues.php");

$venue = new venues;

$thedate = $venue->listAllVenue();              

if (count($thedate)) {
    for ($i =0; $i < count($thedate); $i++) { 
        $id = $list[$i]['id'];
        <a href="<?php echo venues::theurl($list[$i]['id'], "venue"); ?>"><?php echo $list[$i]['venue_title']; ?></a>
    }

venues.php
class venues{
    function OneVenue($id, $point='id') {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM venues WHERE id = '".$id."'";
        $sql = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

        if ($sql) {
            $result = array();
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
            $result['id'] = $row['id'];
            $result['venue_title'] = $row['venue_title'];
            return $result;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }   

    function theurl($id, $point="", $type="") {
        if ($point == "venue") {
            $data = venues::OneVenue($id);
            $id = $data['id'];
            $thename = trim(strtolower($data['venue_title']));

            $urlLink = explode(" ", $thename);
            $sublink = implode("-", $urlLink);

            $result = URL."venue-details/".$id."/".$sublink."/";
        }
    return $result;
    }
}

landing.php
include_once("venues.php");
$venue = new venues;

if (isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $pickvenue = $venue->OneVenue($id);
    echo $pickvenue['venue_title'];
}

.htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^venues/([a-zA-Z)([0-9]+)/(.*?)/$ venue-details?id=$1


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: in venues.php you're using a global variable `URL` in the line `$result = URL."venue-details/".$id."/".$sublink."/";` Have you explicitly set this global variable somewhere? It should look something like `define('URL', 'www.mysite.com');` or something similar.

Comment: Also in the same file, your doing an sql query (which by the way is vulnerable to sql injection) but I don't see any connect to the database function.

Answer (score 0):

Your index page is broken

your code

```
include_once("venues.php");
$venue = new venues;

$thedate = $venue->listAllVenue();              
if (count($thedate)) {
for ($i =0; $i < count($thedate); $i++) { 
$id = $list[$i]['id'];
<a href="<?php echo venues::theurl($list[$i]['id'], "venue"); ?>"><?php echo $list[$i]['venue_title']; ?></a>
}
```

**Why it's invalid**

```
if (count($thedate)) { // <- has no closing bracket
    for ($i =0; $i < count($thedate); $i++) { 
        $id = $list[$i]['id'];
        // the line below just starts hmtl output with no closing php tags
        <a href="<?php echo venues::theurl($list[$i]['id'], "venue"); ?>"><?php echo $list[$i]['venue_title']; ?></a>
    }
```

Change it to the following and try again;

```
include_once("venues.php");
$venue = new venues;

$thedate = $venue->listAllVenue();
if (count($thedate))
{
    for ($i =0; $i < count($thedate); $i++)
    { 
        $id = $list[$i]['id'];
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo venues::theurl($list[$i]['id'], 'venue'); ?>"><?php echo $list[$i]['venue_title']; ?></a>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: still giving me the same error(Internal Server Error)